# How can I save a telegram audio file directly to S3 from Telegram?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to save a user-sent Telegram voice message directly to S3. This happens inside AWS Lambda so saving to disk and using s3.upload_file(filename,...) will not work. This fails:

```
def audio_handler(update, context):
    message = update.effective_message
    file = message.voice.get_file()
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(file, Bucket='mybucket', Key='onelove.ogg')

ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

If I attempt to use

```
s3.upload_fileobj(BytesIO(file).getbuffer(), Bucket='mybucket', Key='onelove.ogg')
```

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'File'

Comment: "so saving to disk and using s3.upload_file will not work" why not?

Comment: because the process runs in AWS Lambda which is, locally, a read-only system

Comment: Lambda allows you to write to `/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

[`Voice.get_file`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.voice.html#telegram.Voice.get_file) returns an object of type [`File`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File). To download the voice to memory, you can e.g. pass an empty `BytesIO` object to the `out` argument of [`File.download`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download). Please also have a look at the wiki section on [working with files and media](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.